# Weird problem with BEVEL modifier

Tags: modeling

In the image below you can see a switch button selected and its modifier set to 0.001 (1 mm) of bevel.
As you can see, the scale of the object is 1,1,1.
Right below the button is the plaque, also with the **same exact** bevel modifier. All the values are the same, and also the plaque is scaled 1,1,1.
Yet the bevel size is totally different.
Wasted half an hour already to try to understand what can be wrong here, but I really can't get it.

[image: BUTTON SELECTED]

[image: PLAQUE SELECTED]

Comment: Can you share your blendfile at https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/help/?

Comment: @Carlo here you go: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3M6pxSkw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The smaller object has Clamp Overlap enabled, so it's not actually being beveled by the shown Amount. You have to disable it.

Clamp ON

[image]

Clamp OFF

[image]

Comment: How did that get activated, this is my next question here XD  Thank you!

Comment: It's active by defaukt. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

change bevel to width type percent, then it works.

Comment: Mhhh it's a workaround, not a solution. Not that I really need precision modeling here eh, but still there seem to be a sort of bug here, and we should reach a final conclusion about this. Maybe a bug report should be filed.